# How to get the bottom navigator height in swiftui

Tags: swiftui

this is my bottom navigator that displays different views.
I would like to know the height of the container of the tabItem.

```
import SwiftUI

struct BottomNavBarView: View {
    struct TabItem {
        var title: String
        var destination: AnyView
        var image_system_name: String
    }


    let tabs = [
        TabItem(title: "Messages", destination: AnyView(ChatListView()), image_system_name: "2.circle"),
        TabItem(title: "Events", destination: AnyView(EventMatcherView()), image_system_name: "1.circle"),
        TabItem(title: "Settings", destination: AnyView(SettingsListView()), image_system_name: "3.circle"),
    ]

    @State private var selectedTab = 1
    
    init(){
    }

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            ForEach(tabs.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                NavigationView {
                    tabs[index].destination
                }
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: tabs[index].image_system_name)
                    Text(tabs[index].title)
                }
                .tag(index)
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

right now its reading the height of the displayed views (763).

i looked at this article but i could not figure it out::

https://www.reddit.com/r/SwiftUI/comments/176ewnr/how_do_i_get_the_tab_bar_and_nav_bar_height/

Comment: "right now its reading the height of the displayed views" What? I don't see anything in your code that reads anything.

Comment: I think using GeometryReader is the right way, disagree with the link above. Or you're encountering special cases here?